# How to change the position of Sharethis share buttons?

Tags: javascript, html

By default the buttons appear on the TOP left side of my website and they kind of coincide with my menu bar so i was wondering if it's possible to make the share buttons appear at the centre(left). Here's the code of it.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ws.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ss.sharethis.com/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: "8f4de18f-bcc0-41c5-89ab-5c8cfd8d0ac9", doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false});</script>
<script>
var options={ "publisher": "8f4de18f-bcc0-41c5-89ab-5c8cfd8d0ac9", "position": "left", "ad": { "visible": false, "openDelay": 5, "closeDelay": 0}, "chicklets": { "items": ["facebook", "twitter", "googleplus", "linkedin", "stumbleupon", "pinterest", "email"]}};
var st_hover_widget = new sharethis.widgets.hoverbuttons(options);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `position` in `options` to `right`. It's not tested.

```
var options={ "publisher": "8f4de18f-bcc0-41c5-89ab-5c8cfd8d0ac9", "position": "right", "ad": { "visible": false, "openDelay": 5, "closeDelay": 0}, "chicklets": { "items": ["facebook", "twitter", "googleplus", "linkedin", "stumbleupon", "pinterest", "email"]}};
```